# Poolish deflated after refrigeration

Tags: bread

After I allowed the polish to rise for approx. 10 hours ( it had risen quite a bit) and I placed in the fridge overnight - I find that the level has dropped from the high it had prior to refrigerating ? Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeast fermentation slows down under refrigeration but does not stop altogether. After 10 hours, the poolish probably exhausted all of its food for the yeast. Putting it in the fridge did not accomplish much of anything afterwards. It needed to be fed again.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but if I may ask you if I’m doing this correctly : 250g flour, 250g water and 5g fresh yeast - this combination allows the Poolish to rise to maximum (before it recedes) only after 9 hours at room temp (20°C) - I can’t seem to be able to do what a lot of others do by having the Poolish rise for 10-12 hours at room temp and then placed in fridge overnight without the whole thing collapsing ( and they only use 0.1% yeast) Can you advise me ?

Comment: Hi Rob, again, when you say I need to feed it.... does it mean that I can proceed with the Poolish at room temp for, let’s say 9 hours and then before placing it in fridge overnight, I feed it , say 50g flour and 50g water ?

Comment: @Audie After the poolish rises, that is the time to add additional flour and water for the rest of your recipe. A poolish is used for flavor for the final dough.